# how to remove the run dialog in LXDE

Tags: lxde

Does anyone know how to remove [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXdp4.png)? why i ask is simple, i am working for a company who is rolling out a Customized DE for customers, in this case a IT business, so i need to remove the RUN dialog so that non IT employee's wont screw around with commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, in any future people having the same problem as I did, you can remove the run command from your start menu in `/home/username/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/panel`
and editing out this line

`item {
        command=run
      }`

once that is deleted the run menu will be gone after you type in a console `lxpanelctl restart`

Comment: I do not think that is enough hower as you also need to remove the alt f2 which is another way to get that run dialog and the super key +r to get that dialog non it people might be able to mess around. You should not have these kebindings in ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml or if you have a custom other openbox .